# Tiles - insertAttribute vs putAttribute - Difference/usage?

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, tiles

I am working with **Tiles** and **jsp servlets** in a web application. Recently, I came across tiles `insertAttribute` and `putAttribute` tags. 
Going over the documentation listed out for both the tags([here](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tiles-jsp/tlddoc/tiles/insertAttribute.html) and [here](http://tiles.apache.org/2.0/framework/tiles-jsp/tlddoc/tiles/putAttribute.html)), the only difference I can make out is:

`putAttribute has to be enclosed in a parent container tag`. 
***Thus, from functionality viewpoint, the tags are similar.***

`putAttribute` has the enclosing constraint whereas `insertAttribute` does not have any such constraint and seems to have more number of attributes which can be used. I suspect `insertAttribute` tag was added later to the tiles framework.

In what scenarios, should one tag(esp. `putAttribute`) be used for another? 
Any explanation/illustration regarding the difference/usage scenario will be welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Form this link

http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tiles-jsp/tlddoc/tiles/tld-summary.html

Inserts the value of an attribute into the page.

This tag can be flexibly used to insert the value of an attribute into a page. As in other usages in Tiles, every attribute can be determined to have a "type", either set explicitly when it was defined, or "computed". If the type is not explicit, then if the attribute value is a valid definition, it will be inserted as such. Otherwise, if it begins with a "/" character, it will be treated as a "template". Finally, if it has not otherwise been assigned a type, it will be treated as a String and included without any special handling.

Example :

```
  <code>
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
          </code>
```

Declare a list that will be pass as attribute to tile.

Declare a list that will be pass as attribute to tile. List elements are added using the tags 'addAttribute' or 'addListAttribute'. This tag can only be used inside 'insertTemplate', 'insertDefinition', 'definition' tags.

Answer (score 1):

Put Atttribute -> you declare what content will be associated with specified attribute name:

```
<definition name="admin-template-metronic" extends="metronic-template" template="/WEB-INF/templates/metronic/tiles/admin.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="html-title" value="Administrative Console"/>
    <put-attribute name="banner-content" value="/WEB-INF/templates/metronic/pages/common/banner.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="footer-content" value="/WEB-INF/templates/metronic/pages/common/footer.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="menu-content" value="/WEB-INF/templates/metronic/pages/admin/main-menu.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

Insert Attribute: it will use the attribute defined up using put-attribute.
In your page, banner-content will be replaced with the content of file "banner.jsp"

```
<tiles:insertAttribute name="banner-content"/>
```